# swipe.js getPos API help needed

Tags: slider, swipe.js

I'm using for a mobile solution the slider "swipe.js" (https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe). Now i would like to use the api-function getPos to return the actually slide. Unfortunatley my code doesn't work:

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
 window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
 callback: function() {
       var pageNumber = elem.getPos();
       alert("P"+pageNumber);
}
});
```

What's wrong? how doest it work?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
var pos = mySwipe.getPos() + 1;
alert( pos );
```

Comment: this is actually not the cur slide, it seems that it's a count